# Showing that $\{x\in\mathbb{Q}:x≤0 \ or \ x^2≤2\}$ does not have a least upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, irrational-numbers, rational-numbers, upper-lower-bounds

I want to prove that $C=\{x\in\mathbb{Q}:x≤0  \ or  \ x^2≤2\}$ do not have a least upper bound in $\mathbb{Q}$

The definition I'm working with is that a least upper bound, $b$ has to be an upper bound, so $b\in\mathbb{Q}$ where $b>x \ \forall x\in C$ and that its the smallest upper bound, so if $c$ is some upper bound, then $b≤c$

I think the proof is to show that while I can find upper bounds, $b$, I will always be able to find a smaller one. I can prove that upper bound exists by having $b$ be positive and $b^2>2$ but I would like to know how you would always be able to find a smaller one. I think I want to subtract $1/n$ to the bound for a small enough $n$ to create a smaller upper bound. And I would like to do this by avoiding $\sqrt{2}$ if possible

Comment: Compare with [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2064126/r-in-mathbb-q-mid-r0-text-and-r2-2-has-no-least-upper-bound), or similar ones.

Comment: Is there a way to do this with the approach of finding a small enough $1/n$?

Comment: I prefer to avoid $\sqrt{2}$ if possible

Comment: Hint: Try to avoid $\sqrt{4}$ or by looking at $\{x\in\mathbb Q:x\le 0\text{ or }x^2\le 4\}\,.$ Now look at $\{x\in\mathbb Q:x\le 0\text{ or }x^2\le y\}$ with some $y$ such that $\sqrt{y}\in\mathbb Q\,.$ Finally look at $\sqrt{y}\not\in\mathbb Q\,.$ Can you avoid $\sqrt{y}$?